# Sharepoint Folder can not be deleted by the creator

Tags: sharepoint

I created a folder in the library. I then selected the folder using checkbox and clicked on "Document Permissions". In the permissions page, I selected all of the users & groups and deleted them accidentally :( . Immediately doing that, the folder disappeared ( possible because I no more have read access. I tried to create a new folder with same name but got an error saying the folder already exist.

Basically I guess the folder does not have any permissions now.
I am now trying to delete the folder but in vain. I get access denied error . So who is the owner of the folder ? Can you please help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try writing some code that deletes the folder.

Place the delete folder command within a "Run with elevated privilages" block.

You are then deleting the folder using the system rights, rather than the rights of a specific user.

Comment: I logged into Sharepoint box and ran the PowerShell script with elevated privilege but I got access denied error.

Comment: My domain account is part of local "Administrators" group.

Comment: Your powershell code runs under a domain account, you need to use C# and run with elevated privilages to run as the sharepoint system

Comment: Yes. that could be the reason because I saw in the task manager, the process was running as my domain account. Good catch

Answer (score 0):

To Delete that particular folder you must be having the FullControl or Contribute permissions, but as you said you are not even seeing that folder so that mean you dont have the read permission either. So to delete that folder use any other account with credenctials which has rights to that folder to read and contribute. or as Lostpacket told you ,write some custom coding to delete that folder and use Run With Elivited priviledges

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the site collection owner had to delete the folder.